# How To connect BItcoin Core with Php

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client

i installed a bitcoind core and i access bitcoin-cli command in linux terminal with developer command(getbalance, getaccountaddress etc.) but i want run this command in php file.

my php code is:

```
chdir('/home/itr/Downloads/bitcoin/bin');
$output = shell_exec("./bitcoin-cli getbalance");
echo var_dump($output);
```

bitcoin-cli file path:

> /home/itr/Downloads/bitcoin/bin

please tell me what i do?

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely not do it this way and use a RPC client. A very simple one is https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of approaches:

1. Use some well written JSON/RPC php client like this [php-json-rpc-http](https://github.com/datto/php-json-rpc-http) [For using via HTTPS] or [php-json-rpc-ssh](https://github.com/datto/php-json-rpc-ssh) [For using via SSH] along with implementing calls on your own based on [Bitcoin's Reference API CallsList](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list). [Bitcoin RPC quick reference](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#rpc-quick-reference) is also very helpful.
2. Completely rely on [PHP-BitconRPC](https://github.com/denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc), which is a well unit-tested all-in-one library using Guzzle